# All Files Are Read Only

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-layout, read-only

I'm running Windows XP and for some reason, every single file and folder on my computer are read only, however, I can still edit them and delete them, but I cannot download files through games such as Counter Strike: Source. I have reason to believe that what caused this was customization of folders. I recently installed a Russian Phonetic keyboard layout to make things easier for me, although, it over wrote the default Russian keyboard layout so I cannot just go into regedit and delete the entry for the layout. Any suggestions as to how I can fix this problem? Or, if you believe it isn't the keyboard layout, what is causing this problem?

Thanks,

--грейм

Comment: If you can edit them and delete them, then they aren't read-only

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has [an article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;313222) on restoring default security settings including NTFS file system permissions. There is also a tool on the page you can download to make the process easier. Microsoft recommends you make a backup before using this in case it produces undesired effects.

There is also the [SubInACL](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E8BA3E56-D8FE-4A91-93CF-ED6985E3927B&displaylang=en) tool provided by Microsoft and a [great blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2006/09/04/739820.aspx) on how to restore permissions with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes and NTFS security aren't the same thing. You are probably referring to the former. That attibute has nothing to do with file security, yet programs do check it to see if they are allowed to overwrite or change files in the folder.

You should be able to remove read-only attribute where necessary.

http://www.febooti.com/products/filetweak/online-help/read-only-file-attribute.html